# How to apply Chi middleware for subroutes?

Tags: go

Given the following sample API using Chi

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5/middleware"
)

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", GetRouter())
}

func GetRouter() *chi.Mux {
    apiRouter := chi.NewRouter()

    apiRouter.Route("/foo-group", func(fooGroupRouter chi.Router) {
        fooGroupRouter.Use(middleware.AllowContentType("application/json"))

        fooGroupRouter.Post("/sub-route", HandleRoute( /* Params */))
    })

    // other routes

    return apiRouter
}

func HandleRoute( /* Params */) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        responseWriter.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)

        responseWriter.Write([]byte("done"))
    }
}
```

When calling the API via

> POST localhost:3000/foo-group/sub-route

I get a 201 with "done". But I want to ensure this endpoint only accepts the content type "application/json", otherwise send back a 415.

Unfortunately the middleware is not working yet. I also tried to test the behaviour with the testrunner

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

func TestHandleRoute(suite *testing.T) {
    server := httptest.NewServer(HandleRoute())

    suite.Run("responds with status code "+strconv.Itoa(http.StatusUnsupportedMediaType)+" if content type is not application/json", func(testing *testing.T) {
        response, _ := http.Post(server.URL, "text/xml", nil)

        if response.StatusCode != http.StatusUnsupportedMediaType {
            testing.Errorf("Expected statuscode %d but got %d", http.StatusUnsupportedMediaType, response.StatusCode)
        }
    })
}
```

Unfortunately the test fails with the message

> main_test.go:17: Expected statuscode 415 but got 201

so it seems the middleware didn't run. How can I fix that?

Comment: What is the value of `server.URL`? Is it hitting one of the routes that is configured with the middleware?

Comment: @larsks The url value is `http://127.0.0.1:43869` but that's just the base url. Yes, it's hitting the route handlers

Comment: Okay. It was unclear to me how `http.post(server.URL, ...)` was hitting the route handlers, since you're not providing any path in that call.